# Pgfplots plots incorrect lines from function to axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using Beamer with Pgfplots. I have a graph that needs to have a series of dashed lines going from a function (trigonometric, intended to be in radian) to the x-axis. The file runs without giving errors but some of the lines don't plot as expected. I originally thought it might be a degree/radian issue, but that doesn't seem to be it, as setting everything to radians just makes the problem worse. In the code I've left some of the lines with the default degree input and some of them with the r option so it's clear that neither case is plotting properly. How do I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{ trig format plots = rad }
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[ axis lines = middle, ticks=none, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, xmin = 0, xmax = 2.3, ymin = 0, ymax = 1.5, clip = false, declare function = {
        f(\x) = 5*cos(\x)*(sin(\x))^(10) + .2*(cos(\x))^9 *exp(sqrt(\x)) + 0.25;
        },
        every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=north},
        every axis y label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=east}]
                \addplot[thick, green!60!black, domain = 0.4:1.8, samples = 400] {f(x)};    
                
                \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i/\j in {{0.4}/{0}, {0.7}/{1},{0.85}/{2}, {1}/{3}}{
                    \edef\tinker{\noexpand\draw[cyan, dashed] (\i, {f(\i)})--(\i, 0) node[below]{$x_\j$};}
                    \tinker
                }
                
                \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1.05, 1.1,..., 1.8} {
                    \draw[cyan, dashed] (####1, {f(####1 r)})--(####1, 0);
                }
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem seems not related to beamer, the output with article class is the same https://pastebin.com/FgrHfqry

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't fix your existing code, but suggests a different method: a `ycomb` plot for the vertical dashed lines, and xticks with labels for the x_j labels.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{ trig format plots = rad }
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        ytick=\empty,
        xtick={0.4, 0.7, 0.85, 1},
        xticklabel={$x_{\ticknum}$},
        xticklabel style={cyan},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 2.3,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 1.5,
        clip = false,
        declare function = {
            f(\x) = 5*cos(\x)*(sin(\x))^(10) + .2*(cos(\x))^9 *exp(sqrt(\x)) + 0.25;
        },
        every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=north},
        every axis y label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=east}
        ]

          \addplot[thick, green!60!black, domain = 0.4:1.8, samples = 400] {f(x)}; 
                
          \addplot [ycomb, cyan, dashed, samples at={0.4, 0.7, 0.85, 1, 1.05, 1.1, ..., 1.8}] {f(x)};   

   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness
You need `trig format=rad` *not* `trig format plots=rad`. It also does not make sense to convert the argument to radians before calling a function containing `sqrt(\x)`.

[image: Graph with dashed lines down to x axis]

For a better method see answer by @Torbjørn T.